# Why won't the video element auto-play?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made this html code to simulate a Windows 95 Startup sequence. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: #000000">
<head>
    <title>Windows 95 Startup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var startup = function () {
            $("body").append('<center><img src="https://springsadvertiser.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/2016/01/win95-hero.jpg"></center><video controls autoplay><source src="https://www.winhistory.de/more/winstart/down/o95.wav" type="audio/wav"></video>');
        };
        setTimeout(startup, 10000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why won't the video element auto-play, and how do I fix it to auto-play without being muted?

Comment: Because its not muted. You are not allowed to auto play videos with sound. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

also look into the audio element. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, a video on autoplay has to be muted. You can mute the audio using the muted keyword as `<video controls muted autoplay><source src="https://www.winhistory.de/more/winstart/down/o95.wav" type="audio/wav"></video>`. But, I doubt this is what you want to do. 
Edit: This is due to [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).